# Detect the entity provided in utterance

Tags: botframework

I am using the following two utterances in same intent

1. Book tickets to California from Mumbai
2. Book tickets from Mumbai to California.

   In this case, Microsoft advises to use the Hierarchical entity to identify the source and destination entity. But Hierarchical entity doesn't support predefined list. If I have to use List entity, then I can't identify the source and destination entity because the entity array will contain Mumbai and California and we will not know which source and destination city. Can any help on the approach.

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: If possible, you could share the details of entities with screenshots that you created in LUIS app so that we can reproduce the issue quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **composite entity**, composed of list entities for the origin / destination portions.

You can check out the tutorial in the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-composite-entity) for guidance of how to implement the solution.